# Scala ListMap deserialization using jackson

Tags: json, scala, serialization, jackson

I am trying to serialize and then deserialize a Scala immutable ListMap using Jackson.

I define `val foo: ListMap[String, String] = ListMap("foo1" -> "bar1", "foo2" -> "bar2")` and then serialize it using jackson. I verified the serialized string and it looked fine. Then when I try to deserialize the string using Jackson, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1 cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.ListMap
    at .<init>(<console>:12)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
```

Any idea how to effectively serialize/deserialize ListMaps?

Answer (score 2):

## Code

The code for Serializing ListMap is

```
val mapper = new ObjectMapper
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
val m = ListMap((5, 1), (2, 33), (7, 22), (8, 333))
mapper.writeValueAsString(m)
```

Deserializing is

```
val str = """{"5":1,"2":33,"7":22,"8":333}"""
val listMap:ListMap = objectMapper.readValue[ListMap](str)
```

with the same Initializing of the mapper like in the serialization example.

## Output

For serialization

```
{"5":1,"2":33,"7":22,"8":333}
```

For deserialization

```
Map(5 -> 1, 2 -> 33, 7 -> 22, 8 -> 333)
```